PHP error log message wont display from $mysqli = require __DIR__
Im testing my database and validation scripts in php. After changing the database password to run the error script, it is not displaying the message, but instead displaying a white blank page.
Im simply looking to display whatever the error message is. Here is my code:
Database.php
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "login_db";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";

# connect to sql database
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection error: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

return $mysqli;

Auth.php
$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";

print_r($_POST);

I've tried changing the path of the php folder, but the results have been the same. Also, I've attached a screenshot of my text editor file path for more context.


How is this problem related to [tag:directory]? Can you share the settings of error_reporting in your app?

Sounds like you just don't have php error reporting enabled in your environment. Check your php.ini settings. Mysqli will throw exceptions by default in php 8.1 or above, so you don't need to write any custom error handling code (and any that you do write won't have any effect). Even in earlier versions you should enable the reporting mode to make your code shorter, more secure and more consistent
